# View engines for non-mvc web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewengine, webforms-view-engine

I'd like to achieve the MVC View Engine behavior in an web forms application. To register a mobile channel in MVC I normally would do something like this

```
public static List<string> UaSurfpads = new List<string>()
{
    "iPad",
    "MicrosoftRt",
    "PlayBook"
};    

protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // register surfpads
    foreach (string device in UaSurfpads)
    {
        DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, new DefaultDisplayMode("mobile")
        {
            ContextCondition = (context => context != null && context.GetOverriddenUserAgent().IndexOf(device, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
        });
    }

    // ...

}
```

This will enable me to create shadow views like `myView.mobile.cshtml`.

Is there any similar way to work using regular web forms in asp.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET WebForm also have mobile features, as well as MVC. Just read this [article](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/add-mobile-pages-to-your-aspnet-web-forms-mvc-application)
Also, [official MS web source for mobile development](http://www.asp.net/mobile)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing native live MVC to handle this.  However, you can achieve this by putting some code in your app to detect and redirect.  [51 degrees](http://51degrees.codeplex.com/) used this approach and created a freely available framework to do all of this.  I'd recommend looking at it, or at least how they achieve their mobile implementation, and mimic it for your site.